# ASP.NET 5 IsPost gone?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

i cant see from the razor view if the Http request is a postback

in MVC 5 we had the `IsPost`

but it does not work by me on MVC 6

i cant even get the Request object in the view

Comment: Try testing: `if (Request.HttpMethod=="POST") { }`

Comment: I'm having trouble thinking of a reasonable scenario in which one would even *want* to access the `Request` object in a view, or would need to know anything about the request which was received by the controller.  It sounds like this view contains logic that shouldn't be in a view.

Comment: as i wrote Request is not avalible

Comment: my goal is to get the `IsPost`, if i cant i wanted to access it from the `Request` but that's also not available for me

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you could create a extension method on ViewContext to access ViewContext.HttpContext.Request and check for the Method. Possibly like this:

```
public static class ViewContextExtensions
{
    public static bool IsPost(this ViewContext viewContext)
    {
        return viewContext.HttpContext.Request.Method == "POST";
    }
}
```

Comment: im trying to find out why it was removed and if there is a similar way they replaced it with, but that will do for now

Comment: It's gone, because it doesn't really make sense in the view and you are able to get this info from everywhere using the different contexts

Comment: exactly. And anyway we shouldn't talk about 'PostBack' in context of MVC ;)

Comment: well i have a contact us form and i didnt want to write a whole lot of Ajex just to get the submit to work and worry about JavaScript ... so i want this simple check and replce the form with a nice message